# Create a custom drop down menu and place dataset value in input

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a custom drop down menu, using HTML, CSS and Vanilla Javascript.

I've managed to get the menu to appear when the user clicks on the the "from" input field, however when I try and click on an option, it wont let you add the value stored in the "code" dataset.

I did get it to work by using setTimeout method, however it is a bit hit and miss sometimes and doesn't seem like a good solution.

Is there an alternative way to get it to work?

```js
function app() {

  var messages = document.querySelector(".messages");

  var inputFrom = document.querySelector(".input-from");

  var inputTo = document.querySelector(".input-to");

  var nearestContainer = document.querySelector(".nearest-container");

  inputFrom.addEventListener("focus", inputToFocusIn, false);

  function inputToFocusIn(e) {

    messages.innerHTML = "focusin event triggered on input-from";

    // add class
    inputFrom.classList.add("input-from--focusin");
    nearestContainer.classList.add("nearest-container--active");

    // remove class
    inputFrom.classList.remove("input-from--focusout");
    nearestContainer.classList.remove("nearest-container--hidden");

  }

  inputFrom.addEventListener("focusout", inputToFocusOut, false);

  function inputToFocusOut(e) {

    messages.innerHTML = "focusout event triggered on input-from";


      // add class
      inputFrom.classList.remove("input-from--focusin");
      nearestContainer.classList.remove("nearest-container--active");

      // remove class
      inputFrom.classList.add("input-from--focusout");
      nearestContainer.classList.add("nearest-container--hidden");

  }

  var nearestStations = document.querySelectorAll(".nearest-station");

  // add event listener to buttons
  for(var nearestStation of nearestStations) {

    nearestStation.addEventListener("click", addToInputFrom, false);

  }

  function addToInputFrom(e) {

    inputFrom.classList.add("input-from--focusout");
    nearestContainer.classList.add("nearest-container--hidden");

    inputFrom.classList.remove("input-from--focusin")
    nearestContainer.classList.remove("nearest-container--active")

    var targetDataset = e.currentTarget.dataset.code;

    messages.innerHTML = "station added to input from field"

    inputFrom.value = "";
    inputFrom.value = targetDataset;

  }

  var switchButton = document.querySelector(".button-switch");

  switchButton.addEventListener("click", clickSwitch, false);

  function clickSwitch(e) {

    var inputFromValue = inputFrom.value;
    var inputToValue = inputTo.value;

    inputFrom.value = inputToValue;
    inputTo.value = inputFromValue;

  }

}

window.onload = app();
```

```css
/* stylesheet */

body {
 font-family: "GRAPHIK";
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #242424;
}

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 outline: none;
}

.container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 background-color: #FF4136;
}

.search-container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 flex-shrink: 0;
 width: 300px;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #FFF;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.form-container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 width: 100%;
}

.input-container {
 width: 100%;
}

.input {
 width: 100%;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 padding: 10px;
}

.input-from {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.input-from--focusout {
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.input-from--focusin {
 border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.input-to {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.switch-container {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.button {
 border: none;
 background-color: transparent;
}

.button-switch {
 height: 100%;
 width: 38px;
 margin-left: 5px;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-image: url(../assets/images/switch.svg);
 background-position: center;
 background-size: 20px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.button-switch:hover {
 background-image: url(../assets/images/switch-hover.svg);
}

.button-search {
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #2ECC40;
 color: #FFF;
 border-radius: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

.button-search:hover {
 background-color: #33e147;
}

.input-container-to {
  position: relative;

}

.nearest-container {
 position: absolute;
 top: 38px;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 padding: 5px;
 border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 100;
}

.messages {
 width: 300px;
 background-color: #FFF;
 padding: 5px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 font-size: 10px;
}

.finding, .show-more {
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 10px;
 font-style: italic;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 5px;
}

.show-more {
 text-align: center;
}

.nearest-station {
 font-size: 10px;
 padding: 5px;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.nearest-container--hidden {
 display: none;
}

.nearest-station--active {
 display: flex;
}

.nearest-station:hover {
 background-color: #FFF;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.logo {
 margin-right: 5px;
}

.nr-logo {
 width: 15px;
}

.station-distance {
 font-style: italic;
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

   <div class="messages">messages here</div>

   <div class="search-container">

    <div class="form-container">

     <div class="input-container">

     <div class="input-container-to">

      <input type="text" class="input input-from" placeholder="From">

      <div class="nearest-container nearest-container--hidden">



       <div class="stations-container">

        <p class="finding">Finding stations closest to you...</p>

        <!-- stations here-->

        <div class="nearest-station" data-code="Leigh-on-Sea">

         <span class="logo"><img class="nr-logo" src="assets/images/nr-logo.svg"></span>
         <span class="station-name">Leigh-on-Sea</span>
         <span class="station-distance">0.6km</span>

        </div>

        <div class="nearest-station" data-code="Chalkwell">

         <span class="logo"><img class="nr-logo" src="assets/images/nr-logo.svg"></span>
         <span class="station-name">Chalkwell</span>
         <span class="station-distance">1.5km</span>

        </div>

        <div class="nearest-station" data-code="Westcliff">

         <span class="logo"><img class="nr-logo" src="assets/images/nr-logo.svg"></span>
         <span class="station-name">Westcliff</span>
         <span class="station-distance">2.7km</span>

        </div>

        <div class="nearest-station" data-code="Southend Central">

         <span class="logo"><img class="nr-logo" src="assets/images/nr-logo.svg"></span>
         <span class="station-name">Southend Central</span>
         <span class="station-distance">3.6km</span>

        </div>

        <div class="nearest-station" data-code="Southend Victoria">

         <span class="logo"><img class="nr-logo" src="assets/images/nr-logo.svg"></span>
         <span class="station-name">Southend Victoria</span>
         <span class="station-distance">3.8km</span>

        </div>

       </div>

       <div class="stations-show-more">
<!--
        <p class="show-more">Show more stations</p> -->

       </div>

      </div>

     </div>

     <div class="input-container-to">

      <input type="text" class="input input-to" placeholder="To">

     </div>

    </div>

    <div class="switch-container">

     <input type="button" class="button button-switch">

    </div>

   </div>

   <div class="button-search-container">

    <input type="button" class="button button-search" value="Search">

   </div>

  </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `setTimeout` in the `inputToFocusOut()` function is indeed the correct way to obtain the desired effect: hiding of the menu must be delayed so that a click on a menu item will register and its callback will fire. There should be nothing hit and miss about it, just set the delay at a reasonable value, say 300ms, and remove the hiding of the menu from the `addToInputFrom()` callback. Actually, you can remove all of the latter function's class-toggling calls, as they are redundant there and may interfere. The menu will be shown/hidden by virtue of `inputFrom` gaining/losing focus.

BTW, why are you using `focusout` and not `blur`?

Answer (score 0):

Using `focusout` event here

> `inputFrom.addEventListener("focusout", inputToFocusOut, false);`

is not right. Because it will be triggered before `click` event. 
When the function `inputToFocusOut` is executed the `.nearest-container` becomes hidden:

> `nearestContainer.classList.add("nearest-container--hidden");`

and that's why `click` event for it and all of its child nodes (we are interested in `.nearest-station` elements) won't be triggered. Instead of `focusout`, use `mousedown` event. With `blur` event it won't work.